# Input Output API

Tags: java

I need help with a program where I must take string inputs from user continuously until the user enters string "end". Then I must print all the inputs that the user entered till "end". I tried using a for loop but I can't get it.

Comment: As others already answered, I also suggest using java.util.Scanner. See this tutorial for further understanding of Scanner. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Comment: The [tag:homework] tag is banned, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152799/signaling-homework-questions-after-the-deprecation-of-the-homework-tag for alternatives.

Comment: Ok :) Last time someone insulted me badly for not putting a homework tag...I don't know what was the deal with him so I put it this time...I will not anymore :)

Comment: Don't submit homework problems here.

Comment: I am just seeking some help.I don't understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use [java.util.Scanner](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/scanning-text-with-java.util.scanner-3.html) for reading and keep checking user input in the condition of while loop.

Comment: Thanks but I have never used Scanner...so I don't really know much about its use...but I will read...:)

Comment: Well, it's a homework, so I won't post a whole solution for you:-)But with Scanner it should be like 20 lines long program, so just try it, it's not so hard:-)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        if (s.equals("end")) {
            break;
        }
        list.add(s);
    }
    for(String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
for(;;) {
    String s = br.readLine();
    if (s.equals("end")) {
        break;
    }
    sb.append(s).append("\n");
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Ummm this is a way of doing it using Collections API...is there a way of doing it using I/O API? Also what is that for loop you wrote? sorry for not understanding.

Comment: Do you mean without Scanner or without List?

Comment: Thankssss...your coding works awesome :D but still is there a way to di it using I/O API?

Comment: Thank you so much :D I learnt about StringBuilder but forgot about using it...thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Robin Use Scanner along with StringBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using I/O API as you wanted:

```
try{
    BufferedReader br = 
                  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
    String input;

    while((input=br.readLine())!=null){
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
            break;
        }
        inputs.add(input);
    }
    for(String str: inputs) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}catch(IOException io){
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you have problem understanding **For-Each** loop then see [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: O.O It has a number of functions that I've never used xD but I will read into it...this works :) thanks :D